# javascript stopped working on ftp upload to host site with errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, ftp, upload

I'm working on a site au.tunit.com/about/faqs and when uploading the web file to the host site via ftp from my desktop the javascript has stopped working. anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It May be file path error that application not found folder path or CDN not found from The Web. You should check from developer tool press F12 key and check error on web browser console and fix the error. also, run this `$.fn.Jquery` command on Browser console to check Jquery work fine or not.

Answer (score -1):

You uploaded broken jQuery file I think